# Store session click in meteor to change UI

Tags: user-interface, meteor, session-variables

I have a list of links in a menu:

```
<template name="menu">
<div id="menu">
    <a class="menu-list-item" id="sports" href="{{pathFor route='sports'}}">Sports</a>
    <a class="menu-list-item" id="music" href="{{pathFor route='music'}}">Music</a>
    <a class="menu-list-item" id="clothing" href="{{pathFor route='clothing'}}">Clothing</a>
</div>
</template>
```

When a user clicks a specific link, I want to store that click in a session and show only that clicked link when routed to the specific template. For example, when I click "Sports", I want to route to the "Sports" template, hide the "Music" and "Clothing" links, and only maintain the "Sports" link on the new route. Of course, when the user clicks the menu again, I want to re-display all of the links again.

I know the click has to be stored in a session, but I'm unsure how to go about selecting the id as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

To set the session you would need something like:

```
Template.menu.events({
  'a click': function (event) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.id;
    Session.set('menuLinkId', id);
});
```

Then create a helper:

```
Template.menu.helpers({
  'currentMenu': function () {
     return Session.get('menuLinkId');
  }
});
```

And use it in your template:

```
{{#if currentMenu}}
<a class="menu-list-item" id="sports" href="{{pathFor route='sports'}}">Sports</a>
{{/endif}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented, but it now seems that the menu is entirely removed. Should I repeat the {{> menu}} on every new template, encapsulated by {{#if}{{> menu}}{{/if}}?

Answer (score 0):

I felt you need a separate template, and this is a bit hacky way.

Continuing to the @Guy's answer:

On click of the link, store id in `session`.

```
Template.menu.events({
  'click a': function (event) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.id;
    Session.set('menuLinkId', id);
});

Show new template on click(or new route)
```

**In** the new template, by default, hide all items

```
<template name="newTemplate">
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="menu-list-item" id="sports" href="{{pathFor route='sports'}}" style="display:none">Sports</a>
        <a class="menu-list-item" id="music" href="{{pathFor route='music'}}" style="display:none">Music</a>
        <a class="menu-list-item" id="clothing" href="{{pathFor route='clothing'}}" style="display:none">Clothing</a>
    </div>

    //remaining content to show
</template>
```

We're hiding all links by default and `onRendered` function

```
Template.newTemplate.onRendered(function(){
   $("#"+Session.get("menuLinkId")).css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: You mean `'click a'`.